# Cannot populate database table during Heroku deployment?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku

I have a django app that runs perfectly well on my local server. Unfortunately, when I deploy it onto Heroku, the behaviour doesn't work as expected. I can see that it's a database related issue as my dropdowns which are supposed to load a list of values from my database are empty in production.

I have checked on Heroku in the 'Ressources' section of my application and there is a database; it also contains all my project tables (django default tables + my main table). All the django default tables are properly populated (I compared them with my local postgres tables and it matched). 
Unfortunately, my main table is empty on Heroku, whereas it is populated as expected locally. I'm not sure to understand what has gone wrong, especially considering that the table itself has been recognized, yet it is empty. I've applied the command `heroku run python manage.py migrate` but it didn't fix the issue. My guess is that my database settings are correct for local deployment but not for Heroku deployment. Nevertheless, I'm not sure at all. I've tried replacing my db settings by the user/host/password/name provided by Heroku but it didn't work. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Here is my settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
import dotenv

dotenv_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")
if os.path.isfile(dotenv_file):
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'myapp.herokuapp.com']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'myappdb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'MyAppPassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. I had to follow these steps:
1/ Create a `dumps` folder in my application folder
2/ Run the following command to dump my data in json format in the newly created folder: `python manage.py dumpdata > myapp/dumps/myapp.json`
3/ Then `Run heroku run python manage.py loaddata myapp/dumps/myapp.json`